# Calling blas ddot from Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython, blas

I'm trying to use the dot product from BLAS library using Cython, but when the compiled module is called appears the following traceback "undefined symbol: cblas_ddot". Executing the np.**config**.show() to see the linked libraries:

```
lapack_info:
       libraries = ['lapack', 'lapack']
       library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
       language = f77

lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'lapack']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    language = f77

openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

blas_info:
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]

blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

And the ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so and readlink -e /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 shows:
/usr/lib/libblas.so.3.7.0

So apparently the  BLAS libraries are linked, but don't find the cblas_ddot. The pyx file:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "cblas.h":
    double ddot "cblas_ddot"(int N,
                             double *X, int incX,
                             double *Y, int incY)

ctypedef np.float64_t dtype_t
def matmul(np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2] A,
           np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2] B):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, j
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t,ndim=2] out = np.zeros((A.shape[0],B.shape[1]))
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=1] A_row, B_col
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        A_row = A[i,:]
        for j in range(B.shape[1]):
            B_col = B[:, j]
            out[i,j] = ddot(
                A_row.shape[0],
                <dtype_t*>A_row.data,
                A_row.strides[0] // sizeof(dtype_t),
                <dtype_t*>B_col.data,
                B_col.strides[0] // sizeof(dtype_t))
```

The compiling file looks like:
    import numpy

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext


    # The Cython modules to setup
    ext_modules = [
        Extension('matmul', ['matmul.pyx'], include_dirs=
        [numpy.get_include()])
    ]

    # Run the setup command
    setup(
        cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
        ext_modules = ext_modules
    )
```

Comment: Can you show how you're compiling it?

Comment: Yes, sir, the post was update with the compilation commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to tell it to link the the library in setup.py:

```
Extension( ... # as before
   libraries=[':libcblas.so.3']
  )
```

The exact library might depend a bit on what you have install. Try `'cblas'` first, if that fails look up what libcblas file you have. Note that you need to link to libcblas rather than libblas.

You might also look up the [Scipy BLAS Cython bindings](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/linalg.cython_blas.html) to save you some time manually creating this stuff (although I think these are for BLAS rather than CBLAS).